# Android w3c DOM Parsing very slow

Tags: java, android, xml, parsing, dom

I'm having some real issues with the parsing within my android app. I'm pulling down a few XML files with a DOM style parser and it's taking almost 20 seconds to do it and run some code on them, the files are no larger than 30KB.

This is some code taken from the method:

Code is below:

```
HttpURLConnection vehicles_conn = (HttpURLConnection) new URL("XXXXXXX").openConnection();
                vehicles_conn.setRequestMethod("POST");                     
                vehicles_conn.setDoInput(true);
                vehicles_conn.setDoOutput(true);
                vehicles_conn.setRequestProperty("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                vehicles_conn.setChunkedStreamingMode(0);
                String vehicles = URLEncoder.encode("LogonToken", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(gettoken, "UTF-8");
                OutputStream vehicles_os = vehicles_conn.getOutputStream();
                Writer vehicles_wr = new OutputStreamWriter(vehicles_os);
                vehicles_wr.write(vehicles);
                vehicles_wr.flush();
                InputStream vehicles_is = vehicles_conn.getInputStream();
                vehicles_wr.close();
                DocumentBuilderFactory vehicles_dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
                DocumentBuilder vehicles_dBuilder = vehicles_dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
                Document vehicles_doc = vehicles_dBuilder.parse(vehicles_is);
                NodeList vehicles_nList = vehicles_doc.getElementsByTagName("UNIT");

for (int temp = 0; temp < vehicles_nList.getLength(); temp++) {
                    //Create a new vehicle object   
                    Vehicle v = new Vehicle();

                    Node vehicles_nNode = vehicles_nList.item(vehicles_temp);
                    if (vehicles_nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {

                        Element vehicles_eElement = (Element) vehicles_nNode;
                        String something = (getTagValue("ID", vehicles_eElement));

.........
```

Now, I have 3 of these (the http connections are only called ONCE however, within the method), it runs through 26 'Units' in the first XML file - let's call it XML1, then iterates through a second, XML2 with 25 'Places', until the ID field matches with XML1, then grabs a few other fields of XML2 and stores them away into an arraylist, then does the same for XML3 with 'Peopel'. Once finished, it goes back to the top and starts again with the next ID in the list.

Now, my problem is that this process needs to be taking less than a few seconds ideally, it's taking 20! For the record this is over Wifi through a 20Mbit on an LG Nexus 4. Can be replicated through a Motoral Defy and Galaxy Ace 2. Does anyone know why it is so slow?

I'm new to Java/Android so I don't know if perhaps I've coded something wrong, or that the XML parsing is just slow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that your code is parsing the XML into a DOM then traversing the DOM once to extract the data you need.  You should consider using a SAX parser and extracting the data on-the-fly as the parsed items are handed to your application.

Comment: Hi Dale - does this still mean I can pull data from each 'node' in the XML separately? I had read that SAX parsers work slightly differently.

Comment: DOM parsers produce an intermediate data structure (a Domain Object Model) then after the parsing is complete your code can navigate around the DOM gathering the information it needs.

Comment: SAX parsers simply pass the items they discover during parsing to your code and let your code do with it what it will -- you could, for example, create a DOM by adding a node every time the SAX parser called your code to say "I found a new element"   Better still you could build the data structure your application actually needs on-the-fly.

Comment: So when you say can you pull data from the node separately -- you don't pull the data, it gets pushed to you.  You get to see each node once so you capture everything you need at the time you see it.  You may also need to keep track of your position in the tree represented by the XML file.  This makes some people believe that SAX is harder, but in my experience you need to know this anyway -- even when you are traversing the DOM tree, so it's not necessarily harder.  Just a different point of view.

Comment: Thanks, I have in fact implemented a SAX parser now, it has three separate handlers that get called from my main network service and the three handlers assign appropriate values to Units, Places and People now. The entire operation before, while using a DOM method, was taking 20 seconds, it now takes around 2.6